# So im new to programming and trying to make a taxform

Tags: python

I want it so that if you input the gross income as anything less than 0, it will ask you to re-input the answer until it gets a positive number but I'm a bit stuck on it.

```py
GrossIncome = float(input("Enter your gross income: "))
   
GrossIncome == <0:
     
print("sorry, could you please repeat that?")
     
print(GrossIncome)
        
if GrossIncome >0:
    break
```

this is what i have right now and if anyone can help me that would be great

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

```
GrossIncome = float(input("Enter your gross income: "))

while GrossIncome < 0:
   print("sorry, could you please repeat that?")
   GrossIncome = float(input("Enter your gross income: "))

print(GrossIncome)
```

This does not take care of the error when entering anything else than a float as input, but you get your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
GrossIncome = float(input("...?")
while(GrossIncome < 0):
    GrossIncome = float(input("bad input")
print(GrossIncome)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
run = True
while run:
    grossincome = float(input("Enter your gross income: "))
    if grossincome > 0:
        run = False
    else:
        print("please enter value more than 0")

print(f"You enterd {grossincome}\n finished")
```